# Implement a inline scrollviewer in Windows Store app with HTML5/JS

Tags: css, html, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am developing a Windows 8 Store app with html5/JS, a reading app. The content page looks like :
[image]

And I'm using CSS-Grid-Layout to manage the page layout like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="contentPagepage fragment">
        <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
            <button class="win-backbutton black-button" aria-label="Back" disabled type="button"></button>
            <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
                <span class="pagetitle"></span>
            </h1>
            <h2>
                <span class=""></span>
            </h2>
        </header>
        <div class="content clearfix" aria-label="Main content">
            <div id="leftContainer">
                <p>Left container</p>
            </div>

            <section id="rightContainer">
                <div id="navContainer">
                    <button type="button">button 1</button>
                    <button type="button">button 2</button>
                    <button type="button">button 3</button>
                </div>
                <!--<article>-->
                    <div id="contentContainer" class="item-content" aria-label="Main content">
                    html content 
                    </div>
            </section>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

And the css file is:

```
.contentPagepage, .black-button {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: black;
}

.clear{ clear: both; }
.clearfix:after{ 
content:"."; display:block; height:0; clear:both; 
visibility:hidden; 
font-size: 0;
}

*html .clearfix{ 
 height:1%; 
}

*+html .clearfix{ 
 height:1%; 
}

.contentPagepage .content {
    -ms-grid-row-span: 2;
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 40% 60%;
    height: calc(100% - 183px);
    margin: 133px 120px 0 120px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#leftContainer {
    height: calc(100% - 183px);
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    background-color: greenyellow;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

#rightContainer{
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-rows: 30px auto;
}

#navContainer {
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
}

#contentContainer {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: calc(100% - 0px);
}

.contentPagepage .content #contentContainer {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    height: auto;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Now the layout system works fine, but the content area got fixed too, this means if I use the "lement.querySelector(".content .item-content").innerHTML = item.content;" to load some html content, there is no scrollbar even the conent's height is larger than the container.

So, how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the "`.contentPagepage` `.content` `#contentContainer`" block from CSS.
Then replace the `#rightContainer` and `#contentContainer` with this:

```
#rightContainer{
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
    -ms-grid-rows: 30px 1fr;
    display: -ms-grid;
    height: calc(100% - 183px);
}

#contentContainer {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi @troll, thanks for ur advice.Now the problem is that I can scroll the #rightContainer, but only with a little height,namely I can't scroll down to the bottom of the #rightContainer.

Comment: It's working for me. I also checked it with simulator. Are you sure that you pasted the same code that you are using right now, because for me it looks different from the screenshot you took?